# Fedora after dd reinstall

Tags: backup, fedora, dd

I made a Fedora backup, then used Windows 7 for some time and tried to install Fedora back using dd command (under live cd), but now, it loads with black screen and says to look to journal: journalctl.

There are errors: fsck failed with error code 8; Failed to mount /sysroot and so on.

The commands I used:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M conv=noerror | gzip > OS.gz

sudo dd if=OS.gz bs=1M conv=noerror | gunzip > /dev/sda

sudo partprobe /dev/sdaY

sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdaY
```

What do I need to do to reinstall Fedora using existing backup?

Comment: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M conv=noerror | gzip > OS.gz`, makes an image of *sda* but, with `conv=noerror`, if an error occurs in a block, that block is discarded, and **all next blocks** lose its original offset and this can create reading errors, even in data without errors, because of its wrong offset; when you use *noerror*, you probably wanna use `conv=noerror,sync`; with 'sync', you preserve the original offset of data. Besides, if I wanted to make a backup, I would try without any *conv* first.

Comment: Thank you. So, my existing backups are bad:( to be sure, are all other commands I use correct?

Comment: What is `/dev/sdaY`?; you can follow the progress with **pv**, like this: `dd if=/dev/sda bs=1M | pv | gzip > OS.gz`, and then `gunzip -c OS.gz | pv | dd of=/dev/sda bs=1M`; for "the best" *blocksize* in performance, you can do some test first; Why you change the *UUID* of **sda**? When you clone the partition with *dd*, you also clone the *UUID* and, in this case, I think that  is good: if **sda** is identify by its *UUID* in some part of the system, and you change it, you probably are breaking something; unless you perfectly know what are you doing, don't change it.